# scp transfer becomes very slow when the file size is greater than 64KB

Tags: networking, raspbian, scp, file-transfer

The initial problem was that when performing `git clone` via ssh the transfer rate is very slow, then it pauses and finally fails with

> `connection reset via peer`

**Background**

- ssh server is a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian
- ssh client I have tried with both an OSX as well as another Raspberry with Raspbian but have the same issue
- `git clone` on the LAN is never an issue but when attempted over the WAN shows this problem, I do have an openWrt router that has port forwarding to expose the ssh port of the raspberry pi onto the router for WAN access
- I do have a firewall running on the router that is visible from the Internet.
- IPv4 is being used
- RPi is connected to the router via a wired connection
- The following ssh clients were used:

  - OSX: `OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3`
  - RPi: `openssh-client/stable,now 1:7.9p1-10 armhf`

**scp observations**
I said let me try `scp` to make sure this is working fine before I look at `git clone`. Here are my observations:

`scp` of files smaller than 64KB is very fast and done under a second.

```
scp -P 31415 user@host:/tmp/64KB /dev/null

64KB                 100%   64KB 310.4KB/s   00:00
```

`scp` of files larger than 64KB is very slow, even if I just have 1 extra KB, and sometimes fails

```
scp -P 31415 user@host:/tmp/65KB /dev/null

65KB                 100%   65KB 284.2KB/s   00:00
Connection to xxxxxxx closed by remote host.
```

I tried to do an `scp -vvv` and did a diff of the two transfers and I see the following differences.

```
-64KB                                              100%   64KB 288.5KB/s   00:00
+65KB                                              100%   65KB 267.3KB/s   00:00
 debug3: receive packet: type 96
 debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
 debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
@@ -190,6 +190,18 @@ debug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
 debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
 debug3: receive packet: type 97
 debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
+debug3: receive packet: type 98
+debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
+debug3: send packet: type 100
+debug3: receive packet: type 98
+debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
+debug3: send packet: type 100
+debug3: receive packet: type 98
+debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
+debug3: send packet: type 100
+debug3: receive packet: type 98
+debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
+debug3: send packet: type 100
 debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
 debug2: channel 0: almost dead
 debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
```

I do see that with the 65KB I see some addition `+debug3: receive packet: type 98`, but I lack the understanding to interpret this.

I have already gone through few solutions like turning of TCPTimestamps, changing the MTU size, etc, but none of them helped.

Comment: On the RPi itself, you have no problem creating a 65Kb file in the location you want to scp to?

Comment: What is the actual `scp` command line. Are you using wired/wireless, IPv4/IPv6?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille  Yeah I can create a 65KB file without any issues on the target. There is plenty of space.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani
The scp command is as follows `scp -P 31415 user@host:/tmp/65KB /dev/null`, when I wanted the log I did `scp -vvv -P 31415 user@host:/tmp/65KB /dev/null`

Comment: The RPi is connected via wired connection. The client is a remote accessing via internet.
IPv4 is being used.

Comment: I tried your command (openssh 1.7.9) and the debug information is exactly the same for 64k and 65k. It's strange you have different output. Have you changed the configuration of the ssh server, do you have a firewall between the hosts?

Comment: I have [found something](https://medium.com/@rafavg77/cant-complete-ssh-connection-after-successfully-send-the-password-with-rasbian-buster-96dfbbc9a22) Look into your router. My best guess is there's going to be some _passthrough_ enabled, not neccessarily SSH related. You could also replace the router just to try it out.

Comment: First step is to run Wireshark on as many points of the transmission chain as you can, to see what goes wrong (dropped packets? retransmitted packets? Something else?)

Comment: "scp -P 31415 user@host:/tmp/65KB /dev/null"  means the target is /dev/null.  Your problem is not writing, but reading.

Comment: What is the ssh client?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille
ssh client is: 
* `OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3` OSX client
* `openssh-client/stable,now 1:7.9p1-10 armhf` when using another RPi to test

Comment: @EduardoTrápani
Yes I do have a firewall on my router. The router is externally visible on the internet and the issue occurs only when I try to scp over the internet.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I will try that out. Replacing the router is a little harder, as I need to get a similar one and setup access via Internet using the same steps as before, so I might end up with the same issue. I tried the same scp from my friends router over the internet and I get the same issue.

Comment: Thought so, replacing router setup is rather inconvenient... Ok.

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that out.

Comment: If you are asked for more information then you should add it to your question, not (just) put it in a comment. Reading the question should be enough. The comments shall improve the question.

Comment: @HaukeLaging Thanks for follow up, I have updated the question with responses to the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting "IPQoS" to "none" fixed the problem. Thank you so much! I seemed to need to set the option on both the client and server.